# Localization for storyboard objects and foundation objects. How to use the same files?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1, nslocalizedstring

I want to implement localization in Xcode 6 and seems everything works good.

After I pressed localize button in storyboard Xcode has crated two different files for each languages I use.

This is localization file:

```
/* Class = "IBUIButton"; normalTitle = "More\nApps"; ObjectID = "F2X-dg-Vvg"; */
"F2X-dg-Vvg.normalTitle" = "More\nApps";

/* Class = "IBUIButton"; normalTitle = "Parents"; ObjectID = "kwk-af-Aei"; */
"kwk-af-Aei.normalTitle" = "Parents";

/* Class = "IBUIButton"; normalTitle = "Unlock all puzzles"; ObjectID = "tFb-hm-HC6"; */
"tFb-hm-HC6.normalTitle" = "Unlock all";
```

My question is how I can use this code below to get localized string:

```
NSString *str = NSLocalizedString(@"kwk-af-Aei", nil);
```

Right now it return **kwk-af-Aei** string but I expect to get **Parents**.

Does it mean that I should duplicate localized strings for storyboard and for write my code? I mean use different files?

Comment: What happens when you try `NSLocalizedString(@"kwk-af-Aei.normalTitle", nil);` ?

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocalizedString` is for the file `Localizable.strings`. You need to use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` with a specific table like this.

```
// Main.strings is localized table for Main.storyboard.
NSString *str = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"SEt-7V-WkD.text", @"Main", @"");
```

[image]